# Install mysql-workbench in fedora 21

Tags: fedora, mysql

I already install mysql-workbench in fedora 21 from rpm:

```
yum localinstall mysql-workbench-community-6.3.5-1.fc21.x86_64.rpm
```

But when I tried to launch apps by command:

```
/usr/bin/mysql-workbench --help
```

I got the error:

```
/usr/libexec/mysql-workbench/mysql-workbench-bin: error while loading shared libraries: /lib64/libtinyxml.so.0: file too short
```

I don't know how to fix it. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Do you check if you have enough space left on your devices ?
You can try to reinstall libtinyxml library or mysql-workbench on your system ...